# taskmanager be killed when canceling failed task

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, taskmanager

I start flink（bin/start-cluster.sh）on a single machine, and submit a job by flink web UI.
If there are something wrong with the job, such as sink mysql table does not exist or wrong keyby field, not only this job failure, I have to cancel failed task, but after cancelling ,the taskmanager seems like be "killed", it disappears in flink web ui.

Are there solutions for fault tolerance(taskmanager be killed by failure job) ? 
The only way is to run flink on yarn?

Answer (score 0):

A task failure should never cause a TaskManager to be killed. Please check the TaskManager logs for any exceptions.